# How to delete specific values on spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried already to drop but, the values is still there, the workaround was that I create another data frame like this

```
df_trans_new = df_transactional.filter("Quantity>=0")
```

`df_trans_new.show()`   but I want to eliminate the negative entris from that column . thanks a lot

Python:

```py
df_transactional = spark.read.option("sep", ",") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/transactional_dataset.csv")
df_trans_new = df_transactional.filter("Quantity>=0")
df_trans_new.show()
```

```
---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|         Description|Quantity|   InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerID|       Country|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|   536365|   85123A|WHITE HANGING HEA...|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     2.55|     17850|United Kingdom|
|   536365|    71053| WHITE METAL LANTERN|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     3.39|     17850|United Kingdom|
|   536365|   84406B|CREAM CUPID HEART...|       8|12/1/2010 8:26|     2.75|     17850|United Kingdom|
|   536365|   84029G|KNITTED UNION FLA...|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     3.39|     17850|United Kingdom|
|   536365|   84029E|RED WOOLLY HOTTIE...|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     3.39|     17850|United Kingdom|
|   536365|    22752|SET 7 BABUSHKA NE...|       -2|12/1/2010 8:26|     7.65|
```

I need to eliminate all negative entries on the column quantity

Comment: Dataset(DataFrame) is immutable. You cannot change values in place. You always get new dataframe/dataset by applying transformations. What you did is correct.

Comment: I drop all null values on the df_transactional, and i would like to do the same with the negative values in a certain column. so , i can drop the null but i can not eliminate some values on a certain colum?

Comment: Please add sample input dataframe and expected output  dataframe, it will help us give a better answer.

Comment: already update the question

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using python, I tried and it does work in both pyspark and scala:

Python:

```py
df_transactional = spark.createDataFrame([("a", -1), ("b", 1), ("c", 0)], ["Name", "Quantity"])
df_trans_new = df_transactional.filter("Quantity>=0")
df_trans_new.show()
```

Scala:

```scala
val df_transactional = Seq(("a", -1), ("b", 1), ("c", 0)).toDF("Name", "Quantity")
val df_trans_new = df_transactional.filter("Quantity>=0") 
df_trans_new.show()
```

Both results in:

```
+----+--------+
|Name|Quantity|
+----+--------+
|   b|       1|
|   c|       0|
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Yes , i am using python. and that was exactly what i did, seems so

Comment: df_transactional = spark.read.option("sep", ",") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/transactional_dataset.csv")

Comment: I suggest you check the code if you are really show()ing the correct variable for the final result, this sort of filter does work.

Comment: seems so, i ask to .show(all_the records) and no one came negative

Comment: but I though that could be some function that goes trough all the rows on that specific column and eliminates all negatives entries

Comment: The `filter` function eliminates the records that match the criteria.

Comment: that was my thinking since i could not be able to eliminate the negatives entris. so i though that i will run a filter and then save in a new df. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tried using your data in scala (Functionality is same in python too) and it worked well-

```scala
val data1 =
      """
        |InvoiceNo|StockCode|         Description|Quantity|   InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerID|       Country
        |   536365|   85123A|WHITE HANGING HEA...|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     2.55|     17850|United Kingdom
        |   536365|    71053| WHITE METAL LANTERN|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     3.39|     17850|United Kingdom
        |   536365|   84406B|CREAM CUPID HEART...|       8|12/1/2010 8:26|     2.75|     17850|United Kingdom
        |   536365|   84029G|KNITTED UNION FLA...|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     3.39|     17850|United Kingdom
        |   536365|   84029E|RED WOOLLY HOTTIE...|       6|12/1/2010 8:26|     3.39|     17850|United Kingdom
        |   536365|    22752|SET 7 BABUSHKA NE...|       -2|12/1/2010 8:26|     7.65|    17850|United Kingdom
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS = data1.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    df.filter("Quantity>=0").show(false)
```

Output-

```scala
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|Description         |Quantity|InvoiceDate   |UnitPrice|CustomerID|Country       |
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|536365   |85123A   |WHITE HANGING HEA...|6       |12/1/2010 8:26|2.55     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |71053    |WHITE METAL LANTERN |6       |12/1/2010 8:26|3.39     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |84406B   |CREAM CUPID HEART...|8       |12/1/2010 8:26|2.75     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |84029G   |KNITTED UNION FLA...|6       |12/1/2010 8:26|3.39     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |84029E   |RED WOOLLY HOTTIE...|6       |12/1/2010 8:26|3.39     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |22752    |SET 7 BABUSHKA NE...|-2      |12/1/2010 8:26|7.65     |17850     |United Kingdom|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+

root
 |-- InvoiceNo: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- StockCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- InvoiceDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- UnitPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- CustomerID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)

+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|Description         |Quantity|InvoiceDate   |UnitPrice|CustomerID|Country       |
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|536365   |85123A   |WHITE HANGING HEA...|6       |12/1/2010 8:26|2.55     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |71053    |WHITE METAL LANTERN |6       |12/1/2010 8:26|3.39     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |84406B   |CREAM CUPID HEART...|8       |12/1/2010 8:26|2.75     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |84029G   |KNITTED UNION FLA...|6       |12/1/2010 8:26|3.39     |17850     |United Kingdom|
|536365   |84029E   |RED WOOLLY HOTTIE...|6       |12/1/2010 8:26|3.39     |17850     |United Kingdom|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks guys! i will maintain with the previous solution, that is using the filter and use this new df from now on. Thanks